# After 60 days with no activity, a question should automatically become protected

Tags: feature-request, protected-questions

I've been seeing a lot of really old questions being bumped to the front page because a person who most likely found the question on google answers "Yeah me too".

These are two examples:

- [How print the design view?](https://superuser.com/questions/167870/how-print-the-design-view)
- [Only solid color possible as background in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/280486/only-solid-color-possible-as-background-in-windows-7)

I'm sure there are more. In these questions, the answers have been deleted by an admin/votes, but they were there at one point.

That's why I say that all questions that have gone 60 days straight with no activity should become protected.

Comment: Are you not sort of using a sledgehammer to crack a nut here? You want to protect millions upon millions of questions, to save the trickle of questions popping to the top of the "active" list due to a *few* "Me to" posts?

Comment: It takes just a second to see that it's a "Me too" and flag it for the moderators, and it seems like extreme overkill to protect all inactive questions because there are a few "me too" posts to a minute percentage of questions.

Comment: Also, you lose the chance of a new user stumbling across the question, not finding an answer, fixing it themselves and posting an answer. Which happens waaaaay more frequently than might be expected.

Comment: [That first question](http://superuser.com/questions/167870/how-print-the-design-view) doesn't have any deleted answers. The answer that is there *is* subpar, but does at least try to answer the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a question has three deleted answers from < 10 rep users, [Community ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) will step in and automatically protect it. Thus, all you need to do when you spot non answers is to use your flags (or delete votes, if you have sufficient rep).

I think that's a good enough system, there's little reason to close the doors to every new user just because a question is old. If there are clear signs of trouble (deleted answers), sure, but if there are not, what's the point?

Comment: what is the issue about questions having deleted answers?

Comment: @Skippy We don't delete answers unless they don't even attempt to answer the question. I never understood why anyone would click "post your answer" to post anything but an answer, but a lot of new users post comments or follow up questions (or random words) as answers. Now, each new answer bumps the question to the front page, displacing other questions from the front page in the process. We don't want that to happen for non answers, thus the auto protection when they appear in bulk.

Comment: thanks Yannis, makes perfect sense.